Как правильно отобразить число если количество знаков после 0 меньше, чем отображаемое число
Ввожу стороны равностороннего треугольника 1e-10 и программа спрашивает сколько нужно оставить чисел после запятой, и я ввожу 12 например (у меня стоит ограничение от 1 до 12 по тз) и програма вычисляет площадь, высоты, бессектрисы и т.д а для отображения например площади нужно больше чисел после запятой.
Как реализовать в if проверку больше ли у площади знаков после запятой чем наше введенное ограничения или проверка отображает ли printf площадь только с нулями и если да, то число отобразится через экспоненту.
Применый воспроизводимый код:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h >
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int decimal = 0;
    double number = 0;
    double area, p, pp;
    printf("Enter number /n");
    scanf_s("%f", &number);
    printf("Enter the number of decimal places(from 0 to 12): \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &decimal);
    if (decimal > 12 || decimal < 0) {
                printf("The number of decimal places is more than 12 or less than 0 \n");
    }
    double p = numbera + numberb + numberc;
    double pp = p/2;
    double area = sqrt(pp * (pp - numbera) * (pp - numberb) * (pp - numberc))
    if(){ ///Проверка больше ли у `area` знаков после запятой чем наше введенное ограничение `decimal` или проверка отображает ли `printf` `area` только с нулями и если да, то число отобразится через экспоненту
        printf("Area: %.e \n", decimal, area);
    }
    else{
        printf("Area: %.*f \n", decimal, area);
    }
}
    



да, извините некоректно написал. суть в том что например у меня ограничение 12 чисел после запятой, а число например 0.00000000000001 и мне нужно отобразить его, но из-за ограничние pritntf выведет 0.000000000000 и мне нужно написать if который будет проверять то больше ли у числа знаков после запятой чем у нашего введенного ограничения НУ ИЛИ проверять выводится ли данное число хотябы с одним ненулевым числом после запятой и если только нули , то число отобразится через экспоненту, в случае площади: printf("Area: %.e \n",  area);

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Если вы просили напечатать k знаков после запятой числа x и увидели одни нули, то x < 0.510^-k*. Вот это условие и проверяйте.

Увидеть десять или двеннадцать нулей после запятой - небольшое счастье. Человеку будет трудно их даже просто сосчитать. Используйте экспоненциальный формат, это удобнее для программиста и для пользователя.

Чтобы определить количество знаков после запятой берем логарифм по основанию 0.1; по свойству log(a, b) = ln(b) / ln(a), получим: if ((log(area) / log(0.1)) > decimal), где log - натуральный логарифм (ln в математических обозначениях). Если area больше единицы - желаю здоровья, удачи, семейного благополучия.
